# Justify that a relation is asymetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

how to demonstrate that the Relation H included in relation L (**H ⊆ L**) is antisymmetric given that relation L is antisymmetric

i am eventually using its formula:
**∀x,y ∈ A((x,y) ∈ H ∧ (y,x) ∈ H⟹ x=y)**

which return **∀x,y ∈ A( True )** which is equal to **True** so i have **True ⊆ L**

does it answer the question? if no how then can i solve it?

Comment: This is not a "formula", it is a definitional statement of antisymmetric relation which you have observed to hold true for $H$. So $H$ is antisymmetric.